# Spam alerts in notification bar

Tags: motorola-droid-x, notification-bar, airpush

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

I get spam alerts about free ipads and typical junk like that on my notification bar when I start my droid. This also happens when I first connect to WIFI on my home router (secured). I use a DROID X.

Comment: Sounds like you might have installed an app that's using [Airpush](http://phandroid.com/2011/04/30/airpush-sends-ads-to-your-notification-pane-and-why-i-think-its-horrible/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get this [Air Push Detector app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5icm9zbWlrZS5haXJwdXNoZGV0ZWN0b3IiXQ..) to find out what is creating those notifications.

Then uninstall the app(s) that are creating them.

Comment: What if Air Push Detector doesn't find anything, but you're still getting the ads?

Answer (score 3):

The **AirPush Detector App** is way to go (+1 Bryan).
It very nicely also lets you quickly uninstall the offending app.

Just in case people are looking, there is also an [Airpush Permanent Opt out](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.airpush.optoutapp&hl=en) from AirPush.com;
they also suggest entering your IMEI at their site...
**I have not done either and suggest you do not do such things too.**
<sub>In a way this seems like an anti-answer; I suggest you use Bryan's way over AirPush's one to opt out. Hope the Irony is not wasted.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the Airpush suggestions. One way to find the offending app is to look at the list of running apps and kill them one by one until the notification disappears. Note, when this happened to me, it was from a First Aid app that I've since uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the option that you can manually opt out of airpush notification by going to http://m.airpush.com/optout and click the "manual opt-out" button.

You enter your IMEI (found in the "About Phone" info screen).

Answer (score 0):

This Problem solved in Android 4.1.
its about hold on the notification and you will get the application information.
you can disable the Application notification.