# Red Star And Green Cross Icons?

Tags: notifications, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

I have a Motorola Defy and in the notifications bar I am always getting red stars and bright green crosses. The Red Star is advertising 'dating' and 'meet hot couples' and the green cross is advertising 'get free apps now' 'win an ipad' and stupid things like that. The apps I have on my phone are [Wheres my water](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.WMW), [a flashlight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.telemarks.xperialed&hl=en) [map my run](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapmyrun.android2&hl=en), [picsart](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picsart.studio) and two live wallpapes i got for free. Please help me get rid of these.

Comment: Not familiar with the green cross one, but the red star notification ad sounds like [Airpush](http://phandroid.com/2011/04/30/airpush-sends-ads-to-your-notification-pane-and-why-i-think-its-horrible/). Does it look like the screenshots in [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18232/981)?

Answer (score 6):

Install [Addons Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector) or [Airpush Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector) to find apps which are causing those push notifications. And, uninstall those detected nasty apps.

If you are rooted, you can install [Airblocker - Airpush Block](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.byq.airblocker). It simply blocks airpush notification and you'll not have to uninstall those nasty apps.

Comment: I don't agree with using Airblocker, just uninstall it and find an alternative app unless you want what-ever nasties is in there doing things behind your back. If you really are desperate to use this app, may I suggest the usage of DroidWall to block it also. Just saying :)

Comment: DroidWall provides firewall... What if the app needs to go to internet. Just to block Airpush ads, would you like to make the app unusable?

Comment: Airblocker blocks airpush ads by adding entries in host file...