# Strange icons and notifications, is there a malware in my phone?

Tags: security, malware, airpush

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it)
>   [Red Star And Green Cross Icons?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21151/red-star-and-green-cross-icons)

I have a Samsung galaxy nexus with official Android 4.1 running. I sometimes get strange notifications with a green + as the icon, saying you have won..., click here to..., or similar messages. Of course I would not open any of them as they immediately appear suspicious. I also sometimes get some shortcut icons on the home screen looking like games, etc. I do not find them in the app list though. I have had similar incidents before upgrading to 4.1.

Does anybody get things like these? Is this a malware living in my phone? Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably spam notifications being generated by some third-party app that you have installed.  Quite a few "free to play" games pull this garbage these days.

It could also be malware, but it is more likely that some game you have installed is doing this.

Note that in Android, an application icon does not have a 1:1 correspondence with installed applications; many applications provide different icons (or no icon at all), because of the way that Android applications are put together.

Comment: Is there anyway to identify the app sending the notifications? Or is there any standard way for detecting malware on Android?

Comment: I don't know about on Android in general (or Samsung's specific customizations), but on Android 4.1 Jellybean you can long-touch on a notification and select 'app info' which will tell you which application generated the notification.