# ad on statusbar

Tags: applications, uninstallation, ads, freeware, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out which app is putting ads in my notification bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/how-can-i-find-out-which-app-is-putting-ads-in-my-notification-bar)

Sometimes I get ads on statusbar. These ads came from some free apps. I have lots of installed apps and I can't figure out from which app the ads come from.
Is there any solution to find the app? I would like to uninstall it to get rid of this messages.
Or is there any solutions to block the ads? My phone is not rooted and I don't want to root.

Hubi

Comment: Related: [How can I find out which app is putting ads in my notification bar?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18312/981), [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18232/981), [Is there a reliable way to detect the app responsible for an Airpush ad?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14981/981)

Comment: @eldarerathis You must close this question because its a duplicate...

Comment: One more: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21151/red-star-and-green-cross-icons

Answer (score 2):

The solution use this [AirPush Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en)  - This will flag the apps installed that are doing this intrusive advertising on the status bar.

Personally, and for that reason alone, I steer clear of those kind of apps and uninstall them and nuke it. They are not worth my time to download from.

1. Report it to Google
2. Name and shame the developer and their app.
3. Post 1 star negative reviews and share it with others and get them to blog it, post it to reddit and warn others about it.

From what I can recall, Jelly Bean has the capability to block those status bar notifications? Feel free to reply to correct me if I am wrong :)

***Edit:***

As *Izzy* has pointed out

> According to the updated Playstore guidelines, this technique got banned. For the next couple of weeks it's "grace time" -- but apps having airpush or the like built in will get removed starting in September.

Comment: Stay clear? Sure. But I would also report such an app to Google. According to the updated Playstore guidelines, this technique got banned. For the next couple of weeks it's "grace time" -- but apps having airpush or the like built in will get removed starting in September, AFAIR (30d grace time -- I just don't remember its start day)

Comment: Stay clear? I did not say that but that's good to know anbout the grace time period from google. :)

Comment: AFAIK you are correct that since JB you can find out who (i.e. which app) placed something in the notification area, and to forbid notifications per-app (I have no JB to check, but that's what the changelog says). My opinion on apps using AirPush and similar intrusive ads: 1) report, 2) uninstall, 3) never buy the Pro, 4) do not buy any other app from such developers, 5) make this approach public. So they kill their own business and should be aware of it -- to prevent similar strategies at least to a certain degree (if they know they might think twice).

Comment: Yeah, I **should** have stated, report it and *out the developer*, give 1 star negative reviews and post it on reddit's /r/android and get the pitchforks ready! :)

Comment: exactly! Heat the tar and pluck the chickens! Let's shoot back (not with the chickens, that could cause trouble with Rovio)! :D

Comment: LOL! :D Nice one sir! *clap clap clap*

Answer (score 1):

There are several apps you can use to find which apps are employing which ad networks. Try [searching for "ad network detector"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ad%20network%20detector&c=apps).

Personally, I've used [Lookout Ad Network Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.addetector).