# Silencing notification of scheduled quiet mode (LG G2)

Tags: notifications

I have quiet mode scheduled and it works exactly as I want. The problem is there is a notification every morning that my scheduled quiet mode occurred. I'm starting to hate seeing this notification and I don't need to see it.

Answer (score 1):

What application do you use to enable quiet mode? Is it standalone application or a system app?

If it's a standalone application then you could try [turning off notifications for that app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22708/how-to-turn-off-notifications-for-individual-apps) however note that this will disable all notifications coming from the app, not just the silent one.

Comment: It's the system quiet mode app. Can I adjust notifications for that? I'd like to do the same thing with the Battery Saver thing that always has a thing on my notifications, but the Settings app doesn't let you disable or edit notifications.