# What does "Ignore messages like this" do? How do I see what I've ignored?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications

When I tap and hold on a notification in the notifications list, I get an option to "Ignore messages like this." I can't find any explanation, though, of what this means. Does it really mean, ignore all notifications *from this app*? Or does it mean, only ignore messages *like this one* from this app? (i.e. can one app have multiple "channels" or types of notifications?)

And the other side of this - where can I see what messages I have chosen to ignore, and possibly undo it, if I once again want certain messages?

UPDATE: In CM settings there's a "Notification Filter" screen that lists all notifications that I've chosen to ignore. (Settings > Privacy > Filter Notifications in CM11.) I still don't know what the filter *does*, though - it hasn't seemed to keep me from seeing any notifications.

(I suspect that this feature only blocks you from seeing notifications whose source and content *exactly* matches a past notification, but I can't confirm that so I don't want to post it as an answer. Can anyone confirm or deny?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, this feature seems to hide future notifications when the *same app* shows a notification with *exactly the same text* again in the future. This means you can't filter messages like `[filename] download completed` from the download manager, `[app name] installed` from the app store, or `Level up! You are now level [number]` from Google Play Games, since they have changing content.

As such, its usefulness seems pretty limited. There's no good way to choose which notifications you get from most apps, unless the app has those options built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is simply the standard Android feature for turning off notifications.  It's on a per-app basis, rather than analyzing what kind of notification it is or its contents (etc.).

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/22712/1465) provides the details of how to turn them off or back on:

> Under each application info screen there is now a checkbox for "show notifications" (assuming the app sends notifications). Uncheck that and no more notifications from that app.
>
> You can get to the screen by going to `Settings | Apps | {application}` or, more conveniently, long-pressing the notification itself and then tapping "App Info".

Comment: In cm12 if you go to "settings > notification manager > filter notifications" you can see which ones you blocked

Comment: @saloalv is right, except on CM11 it's under settings > privacy > filter notifications. It appears to be a list of all the specific notifications that I've chosen "Ignore messages like this" on. Those apps do NOT have "Show notifications" disabled, and they still show notifications. I still can't guess what it's supposed to be doing though.

Comment: @Josh preventing from showing same notification? "download completed"?

Comment: @saloalv, I'm afraid that's true, except that almost no app shows the "same notification" twice. Downloads, for example, say "[filename] download completed," so they're different every time. You can't filter them unless for some reason you need to download exactly the same file regularly :)