# How do I turn off email notifications on my Gmail app on Android?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I'm using an LG Tribute phone which I recently purchased for Virgin Mobile.  I have Gmail installed and by default, whenever I get an email, it generates a notification (in my case a buzz since I have my phone on vibrate).

How do I turn off notifications entirely for my Gmail app (don't want any sounds when I receive an email)?

Comment: Do you want to stop only the sound from the notifications but still receive the latter or do you put a stop on any kind of Gmail notification? The last case is a duplicate of [How to turn off notifications for individual apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22708)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe since Gmail has its own settings for notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, if you wanted to disable notifications entirely for the Gmail app (or any other app for that matter), you could do this:

1. Go to Settings → Apps → All Apps tab.
2. Find the app you want to stop receiving notifications for and tap on its entry.
3. Find a check-box for "Show Notifications" and uncheck it.
4. A warning that you might miss important updates will be shown, tap "OK" to continue.

You have now successfully disabled notifications for the app!

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: App Settings Page Example]

<sub>Image Credits Google Images</sub>

Comment: When I open up "Settings" -> "Apps", I don't see a Gmail app. There is a "Google App".  Does that mean I turn off notiricaionts for anything related to Google?  I can't find any app just named "Gmail."

Comment: Look under Settings->Apps->All apps.  Because Gmail is a system app, it won't show up under downloaded apps.

Answer (score 4):

In the Gmail app itself:

1. Slide open the hamburger (3-lines) menu and tap on "Settings".
2. Then tap on the Gmail account that you want to disable notifications for.
3. In here deselect the "Notifications" check box.

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG: Notification setting]

Comment: @Dave, you need to be in the gmail app itself.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 5.0 and up, go to Settings > Notifications > App notifications > Gmail > Block.

You will not get any notification from Gmail app until you change this option.