# How to get rid of ads popup?

Tags: notifications, ads, popup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

Recently I often get the popup ads like the snapshot as below.

I wanna get rid of it. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [Airpush](http://www.airpush.com) ads, and the only way to *truly* get rid of them is to remove the app that is displaying them.

The other way to get rid of them, is to use the [airpush opt out system](http://www.airpush.com/optout) to opt out of airpush ads, this however has been reported to not work by *loads* of users.

As such, the only way to truly get rid of them is to remove the app that is using airpush - uninstall apps you have recently installed, sequentially, until they are removed, or long press on the notification and select the `App Info` button that is displayed. This will take you directly to the app's settings page. (This is only available for Android 4.1 plus).

Comment: On Android 4.0 and before, you can also use apps like [AirPush Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector) or [TrustGo Ad Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trustgo.addetector) to identify the evildoer.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted, you can try [AdAway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adaway).