# How can I find out which app is putting ads in my notification bar?

Tags: notification-bar, ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

Recently advertisements have started appearing as notifications in my phone's notification bar. The icon on the ad are either a green plus sign or a white star with a red circle inside it. There is no indication in the notification as to which app it came from.

I haven't installed any new applications, so I assume that some application updated to include this intrusive new ad system. Ads only show up at irregular intervals once every few hours, so removing all my apps one by one until the ads stop is not really a viable option, since I would have to wait several hours in between each uninstall to see if another ad appears. (I'm sure this is by design.)

So is there any way to figure out the source application of these notification ads?

My phone is a rooted/unlocked/whatever HTC Droid Incredible running MIUI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [several](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it) [previous](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17228/spam-alerts-in-notification-bar) [questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-detect-the-app-responsible-for-an-airpush-ad).

Comment: None of those showed up in the "Questions with similar titles" when I asked this. Sigh. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find by log.
If you have android sdk installed,
run

> adb shell dumpsys notification

The output will have details about all the notifications. Using Package name you can get the app that has been pushing ads

Comment: You might want to post this answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it) instead, since this question has been marked as a duplicate.