# Disable Google Play Ads in Notification Area?

Tags: notification-bar, ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/is-this-red-star-icon-malware-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

I'm not sure if everyone has experienced this annoying behavior, I often see ads in my notification area pointing to games in the market.
Is there any way to avoid this annoying feature I never asked for?

Here is what the ad looks like:

[image][image]

Comment: A similar question that doesn't specifically relate to the red star icon is [Spam alerts in notification bar](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17228/spam-alerts-in-notification-bar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Airpush! A bloody nuisance they are.

Need to figure out which app did you install recently, that is the culprit. Uninstall it, let the developer know that airpush is disastrous and let them see their downloads drop!

If your handset is rooted, you might try [Ad-Away](http://code.google.com/p/ad-away/) to block those pesky adverts. And its open-source and available on Google Play.

Comment: It was removed for violating section 4.4 of the Google Play Developers Agreement, but can still be downloaded at [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.adaway/). Also, the code link to it is broken.